# sending email with images

Tags: c#, smtp

I have a WinForms application where a user can configure email templates that will later get mail merged with client data from the database and then sent via SMTP.

I have everything working fine, but the issue comes when the user saves images inside the template body. I'm using a DevExpress RichEdit control to allow the users to create this email body, and that control converts it to HTML that I use to send. When images are there, it uses data-uri to embed the image directly into the HTML.

The problem now comes when I send the email in this way using data-uri images, not all clients render it properly. I just tested it in Outlook, and it doesn't seem to work. I know some web based email clients will work, but I need this to work all the time, at least for the widely used email clients.

I'm wondering if others have solved this problem and what might be the best solution here? I suppose I could send the images as attachments and then reference the attachment, although I'm not sure if this is a best practice. The other alternative though is to host each image on a server somewhere, then create a service which would have to store the images (like in a DB), and provide a way to query this image over the web using an ID. Then my emails would use an img src=site/getImg?imgID=xxx type thing. However, this seems like a lot of work to do what I want to accomplish and I'm hoping I could avoid it with something easier.

Thanks in advance for any advice!!

Comment: The last option you mention seems to me to be the best one. That way even if your users upload big images, you won't be sending out big emails (or not-that-big emails to a lot of people, resulting in a heavy bandwith anyway). And loading images from an url is also widerly supported. of course this forces you to have a webserver running with the script you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Adding images as attachments will work, but has the downside of a larger payload and higher bandwidth utilization both for you and for your recipients. The code for adding attachments in .net is pretty simple:

```
var message = new MailMessage();
foreach (string path in attachmentPaths)
{
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(path));
    }
}
```

On the other hand, referencing images stored on the web somewhere reduces the size of your emails and also opens up the possibility of gathering tracking data on clients that request images. Of course, most email clients will first ask the user whether they want to download images, so your tracking will only be rough.

Answer (score 0):

you should be try save the images in the local disk , and the next include the who Embedded images.

```
        // Add image attachment from local disk
        Attachment oAttachment = oMail.AddAttachment( "d:\\test.gif" );

        // Specifies the attachment as an embedded image
        // contentid can be any string.
        string contentID = "test001@host";
        oAttachment.ContentID = contentID;
        oMail.HtmlBody = "<html><body>this is a <img src=\"cid:"
             + contentID + "\"> embedded image.</body></html>";
```

Sorry for not explain, I speak only a little in english